# Unable to set the BuiltinDocumentProperties of an Excel file

Tags: excel

I want to set the meta data of an Excel file programmatically.

If I run this code in VBA,

```
ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties.Items("Title").Value = "Hi, there!!!"
```

I get an 'Object does not support this property or method' exception

Excel format (2003 or 2010) does not make a difference.

I cannot get a direct confirmation in MS documentation, but I suspect the `BuiltinDocumentProperties` is read only in Excel.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `Item`, not `Items`, but it is the default method so is not necessary:

```
ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Title").Value = "hi there"
```

It is probably/usually necessary to include `Item` if automating Excel from another application:

```
ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties.Item("Title").Value = "hi there"
```